# store current date and time in the datetime format zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, datetime-format

I have a field called `date_time` in the database which is of type `datetime`.
I have a form which on submit needs to enter the current date and time in the date_time field.
How do I write my code so that the `date_time` field gets inserted with the current `datetime`.
The following is my code: (I know I can't call `NOW()` like that, but I wanted to show what I want to achieve)

```
$qcData = Array(
    "date_time" => NOW(),
    "note" => $note                                         
);

$qcNotes = new App_Model_DbTable_QCNotes();
$qcNotes->insert($qcData);
```

Comment: Do you want to do this in computed in the database or in php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here it is from the docs

> 26.3.1. Current Date Without any arguments, constructing an instance returns an object in the default locale with the current, local date
>   using PHP's time() function to obtain the **UNIX timestamp** for the
>   object. *Make sure your PHP environment has the correct default
>   timezone*.
>
> Example 26.2. Creating the Current Date

```
$date = new Zend_Date();

// Output of the current timestamp Feb 13, 2012 10:28:59 PM 
print $date;
//implement toString() output 2012-02-13 22:30:25
print $date->toString('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: RockyFord I assigned $date_time=new Zend_Date(); but when I insert it displays 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in the database. I shall do a bit more debugging and come back..

Comment: @user856753 make sure your timezone is set correctly in the php.ini, you do know that most Db's will do this for you. In mysql for instance making a field a type = timestamp and attributes on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP will automatically timestamp any updates.

Comment: could it be because the datetime format in the database table expects a different format than $date returns!

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
Zend_Date::now()->toString('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```